In Vue 3, am I supposed to se the whole object structure when initializing a reactive value?
Suppose I want to create an empty value in my pinia store that hold the current subscription model the user is looking at. This should be null/unset if the user is not currently on a subscription detail page.
Flow:
User clicks on the link to go to a subscription detail page of subscription ID 1. In the store, I'll dispatch an action to fetch the details of subscription id 1 and assign the object returned by my endpoint to that reactive variable.
export const useSubscriptionStore = defineStore("subscriptions", () => {
  let currentSubscription: Ref<SubscriptionModel> = reactive(null); // Null is not valid!

  async function loadSubscription(subscriptionId) {
    const { $api } = useNuxtApp();

    const { data } = await useAsyncData(() =>
      $api.subscriptions.getSubscription(subscriptionId),
    );
    currentSubscription.value = data.value;
  }

  return {
    loadSubscription,
  };
});


Am I supposed so set my reactive variable declared in line 2 to the same object structure I expect the backend to return? Isn't it possible to set a reactive variable that is capable both of holding the value null or an object?
In Vue 2, you were able to use Vue.set()

The correct type is SubscriptionModel | null, and it should be ref instead of reactive, especially since the type is already Ref. API functions are commonly generics in TypeScript, this allows to infer a type. Using const instead of let allows to avoid accidental reassignment, which is a common mistake resulting in loss of reactivity.
It should be:
const currentSubscription = ref<SubscriptionModel | null>(null); 


I somehow thought it was intended to alway use ref() for any data type except for objects and reactive() solely for objects. Turns out I was wrong. So basically most of the time I should use ref(), right? Thanks!

In your case null isn't an object (despite what console.log(typeof null) says), so this is not the case. reactive is for the cases where you just need reactive object that isn't completely reassigned. If you compare it to v2, the whole store state could be state = reactive({...}), similarly to data() state in components. This is what pinia does any way with the object you return from store function
